# Package com_atlassian_clover is not visible

Tags: maven, maven-3, java-module, clover

I am experimenting with java modules and unit tests.

So I also have the clover plugin within my maven pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.openclover</groupId>
    <artifactId>clover-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version> 
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/module-info.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>instrument</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

But when running

```
mvn clover:instrument
```

I got the following error:

```
error: package com_atlassian_clover is not visible
  (package com_atlassian_clover is declared in the unnamed module, but module com_atlassian_clover does not read it)
```

How could I fix that? Or do I have to wait until clover will support java modules?

I think it would be not a good idea to include the clover package within my modules-info.java. (Might be a solution, because clover instruments the code).